# Is there a way to import terms into Wordpress?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, import, terms, bulk-import

I'm tired of typing in lists of counries in my "Countries" taxonomies. What's a good way to bulk import a long list of terms into Wordpress ?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but just incase any one else is looking, I just ran across Bulk press plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bulkpress/ and http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-ultimate-csv-importer/ which both look good. I just gave bulk press a try and it worked just fine to drop 48 neighborhoods into a taxonomy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put list in PHP array, loop through it, use [`wp_insert_term()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term) on each.

Comment: Where can i run this code?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to experiment with the WordPress Importer plugin. You may need to export the taxonomy list from one categorization, and then import it. Outside of that tool, the other way would be to import the list in csv format into your database. However, you will need to have the taxonomy list in csv format. I am not sure if you need to import the list of countries multiple times, but am assuming you do since you are "tired" of typing lists.

Answer (score 0):

First create an array with all the terms you want to add, then loop through the array and assign a term for each element of the array using the [wp_insert_term](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_term/) function

```
function create_cities() {
    $cities = array('Madrid', 'Londres', 'París'); // tax terms
    foreach ($cities as $city) {
        wp_insert_term($city, 'cities'); //cities its the tax slug
    }
}
add_action('admin_init', 'create_cities');
```